# Magento2 how to display additional custom total value in shipment email

Tags: magento2.3.3, pdf, totals, extrafee, shipment-email

I have added a new custom cart total (e.g. Extra Fee) in my current project. I made it display on almost every page, email and pdf files. However, I can't able to find a way to display it in the shipment email and pdf.

Magento2 has 'order_totals', 'invoice_totals' and 'creditmemo_totals' blocks inbuilt in core sales module. So I can add my new total reference to these blocks. However, Magento2 does not have a 'shipment_totals' kind block. The total section also does not display on the shipment page in admin. However, it does display on shipment email and its pdf file.

How can I add/set my custom total into shipment email and pdf file? Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks,